# SQL Server OPENROWSET return empty table

Tags: sql, sql-server

i got nested stored procedure and trying to return some report from the store procedure. 
If i run the code below it returns the result.

```html
SET FMTONLY OFF; SET NOCOUNT ON; EXEC [DbName].[dbo].[usrGetBalanceBystore]
  @Customer= "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
  @Store= "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
```

i can find the data from the above select.
and same time if i run the code below it returns only column header with no result.

```html
Select * from OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI',
'DRIVER={SQL Server};Server=Server;Database=DbName;Uid=sa;Pwd=password',
  'SET FMTONLY OFF; SET NOCOUNT ON; EXEC [DbName].[dbo].[usrGetBalanceBystore]
  @Customer= "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
  @Store= "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"')
```

I am doing anything wrong with the above? thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you running the first snippet on the same server, database and user account?

Comment: yes everything on the same server. and same instance also.

Comment: Are there any open transactions that are visible to the first query but not the second?  (You can run `select @@trancount` to check for open transactions.)

Comment: dont understand exactly what you mean , but first and second query are the same. when i put inside the openrowset my procedure not return any data except the column heading. if i try with sample select statement it returns the result.

Comment: Can you run `select @@trancount` in the window where you run the select without openrowset?

Comment: return zero transaction

Comment: Is there anything else FMTONLY related in your code / session / settings etc? Are you changing other settings that might affect (ANSINULLS etc)?

Comment: Nothing like that.

Comment: are u running `openrowset` query in SSMS or have u used any tool?

Comment: inside the SSMS .